# tomcat connection pool does not close connection?

Tags: tomcat, connection, pool

I am running into ORA Cursor exceed issues with a third party application using a tomcat connection pooling.

Besides solving those issues, we wanted to release idling sessions by setting :

```
minEvictableIdleTimeMillis =  60000
timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 60000
```

But somehow, it seems that those session are not released at all (even without any traffic):

```
select  a.value, s.username, s.sid, s.serial#, s.machine, to_char(cast(s.logon_time as date),'hh24:mi:ss') as activesince from v$sesstat a, v$statname b, v$session s where a.statistic# = b.statistic#  and s.sid=a.sid and b.name = 'opened cursors current' and s.username = 'username' order by value desc;
```

This shows me "old" session/cursors and statements that are definitely oder than 1 min.

Am I missing an other option?
Thanks and cheers, E.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is a very tricky topic

**Preface**

the connection pool is designed, to limit the maximum simultanous open connections to a database on one hand and to reuse open connections in the pool on the other.

establishing a physical connection to a databse takes time. this time is 'saved' by keeping the connections open (in the pool).

**Connection-Handling**

before java 7, you have to ensure to close the connection, after it is used. mostly in a finally-block:

```
Connection conn = [retrieve DB-Connection];
try {
    // do something
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // handle exception
} finally {
    conn.close();
}
```

in combination with a connection pool, the connection is not physically closed, its just released to the connection pool, after `Statement`s and `ResultSet`s are closed, to be reusable.

since java 7, the above code should/can look like that:

```
try (Connection conn = [retrieve DB-Connection]) {
    // do something
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // handle exception
}
```

it's the new "try-catch with resources" feature. whenever the try-block is left, the resources within the parantheses of try are closed (autocloseable). the parantheses can contain severeal, semicolon-seperated autocloseable resources.

```
try (Connection conn = [retrieve DB-Connection];
     Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
     ResultSet result = stat.executeQuery("SELECT 1 FROM DUAL")) {
    // do something
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // handle exception
}
```

if the connections arent closed/released manually or handled by "try-catch with resources", the connection-pool has got a configurable fall-back-feature -

> the abandoning feature

which handles unclosed/unreleased (abandoned) connections.

please refer to your tomcat-version related documentation of ["JNDI-Resources how to" -> "JDBC Data Sources"](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#JDBC_Data_Sources). this link relates to version 9.0

> The abandoning feature is disabled by default and can be configured using
>   the following properties:
>
> - removeAbandoned - true or false: whether to remove abandoned
>     connections from the pool. Default: false
> - removeAbandonedTimeout - The
>     number of seconds after which a borrowed connection is assumed to be
>     abandoned. Default: 300
> - logAbandoned - true or false: whether to log
>     stack traces for application code which abandoned a statement or
>     connection. This adds serious overhead. Default: false

**Cursors and the "ORA Cursor exceed"-Exception**

the maximum of open cursors is a variable database-property.

so, by executing a lot of queries within one single connection and not closing 'previous' opened/created resultsets and statements, the `ORA Cursor exceed` exception may occur

the following example leads to five open cursors. in this case, the try-catch with resources is used and the `ResultSet`s, `Statement`s and the `Connection` are closed automatically by leaving the try-block:

```
try (Connection conn = [retrieve DB-Connection];
     Statement stat0 = conn.createStatement();
     ResultSet result0 = stat0.executeQuery(...);
     Statement stat1 = conn.createStatement();
     ResultSet result1 = stat1.executeQuery(...);
     Statement stat2 = conn.createStatement();
     ResultSet result2 = stat2.executeQuery(...);
     Statement stat3 = conn.createStatement();
     ResultSet result3 = stat3.executeQuery(...);
     Statement stat4 = conn.createStatement();
     ResultSet result4 = stat4.executeQuery(...);) {
    // do something
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // handle exception
}
```

its better to split them:

```
try (Connection conn = [retrieve DB-Connection]) {
    try (Statement stat0 = conn.createStatement();
         ResultSet result0 = stat0.executeQuery(...)) {
        // do something
    }
    try (Statement stat1 = conn.createStatement();
         ResultSet result1 = stat1.executeQuery(...)) {
        // do something
    }
    try (Statement stat2 = conn.createStatement();
         ResultSet result2 = stat2.executeQuery(...)) {
        // do something
    }
    try (Statement stat3 = conn.createStatement();
         ResultSet result3 = stat3.executeQuery(...)) {
        // do something
    }
    try (Statement stat4 = conn.createStatement();
         ResultSet result4 = stat4.executeQuery(...);) {
        // do something
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // handle exception
}
```

before java 7, the error may also occur, if `Statement`s and `ResultSet`s arent closed manually and the connection itself isnt closed/released

the following example is a 'bad practice' example, neither the `ResultSet`s and `Statement`s nor the `Connection` are closed

```
Connection conn = [retrieve DB-Connection];
try {
    Statement stat0 = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet result0 = stat0.executeQuery(...);
    Statement stat1 = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet result1 = stat1.executeQuery(...);
    Statement stat2 = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet result2 = stat2.executeQuery(...);
    Statement stat3 = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet result3 = stat3.executeQuery(...);
    Statement stat4 = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet result4 = stat4.executeQuery(...);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // handle exception
}
```

lets assume the maximum for open cursors is 20 and there is one bad-practice-code-snippet, the application may run very fast into the "ORA Cursor exceed"-Exception

in this case, the connection-pools

> abandoning feature

takes care for you and closes/releases the connection(s) and implicitly the `Statement`s and `ResultSet`s within.

**Conclusion**

the

> abandoning feature

is only a fallback.

its better to ensure the `ResultSet`s, `Statement`s and `Connection`s are handled and closed correct.

Comment: thanks! really helpful to understand and get some background info!